# Xraylib installation

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

I am a freshman to UBUNTU (Python 2.7 user), and faced a strange problem while installing python's `xraylib` library. The library is not provided in any official repository and the only possible way to install it is to unpack its '`*tar.gz`' file.

What I've done:

1) I downloaded the '`tar.gz`' file to the '`/Downloads`' folder

2) Executed the following commands:

```
gunzip xraylib-version.tar.gz
tar xvf xraylib-version.tar
cd xraylib-version
./configure
sudo make install
```

I found the package has been installed in the '`usr/local/include`' folder (not in the default `usr/lib/python2.7`). Therefore, in Spyder, I added this folder to the `PYTHONPATH` variable, and after writing '`import xraylib`', I got the message:

> `"No module named xraylib"`

Also, I found it is impossible to drag the `xraylib` folder to the `usr/lib/python2.7` where all the python packages are stored.

Can anyone explain what is the best, and simplest way to install python modules from "`tar.gz`" files, so that the packages can end up in the default python packages folder?

Comment: Hi there, I advise you read the http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and [ask] before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for Your answer!

I tried this way, but I found it failed.

1) I ran this "curl..." command

2) I went to the ../etc/apt/sources.list.d/ folder where I edited the sources.list file by adding (and saving) the lines:

'deb [arch=amd64] http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu xenial stable

deb-src http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu xenial stable'

3) I ran 'sudo apt-get update'

4) Finally, following to writing (I use UBUNTU 16.04):
'sudo apt-get install libxrl7 xraylib libxrl7-dev libxrlf03-7 libxrl-perl'

I got:

'Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package libxrl7

E: Unable to locate package xraylib

E: Unable to locate package libxrl7-dev

E: Unable to locate package libxrlf03-7

E: Unable to locate package libxrl-perl'

Meaning, my system still couldn't locate the source.

Comment: Is your system is 64bit? If not, reinstall to 64bit, it's 2016 now.

Comment: 64 bit - the newest version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are very clear at https://github.com/tschoonj/xraylib/wiki/Installation-instructions#debian-and-ubuntu

```
curl http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/xmi.packages.key | sudo apt-key add -

Next, add the package download location corresponding to your distribution to the /etc/apt/sources.list file (as root):

Ubuntu Precise 12.04:

  deb [arch=amd64] http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu precise stable
  deb-src http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu precise stable
Ubuntu Trusty 14.04:

  deb [arch=amd64] http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu trusty stable
  deb-src http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu trusty stable
Ubuntu Wily 15.10:

  deb [arch=amd64] http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu wily stable
  deb-src http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu wily stable
Ubuntu Xenial 16.04:

  deb [arch=amd64] http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu xenial stable
  deb-src http://lvserver.ugent.be/apt/ubuntu xenial stable
When the sources.list file contains the correct download locations, update the apt cache by running:

sudo apt-get update
After this, one can install xraylib by executing the following command:

sudo apt-get install libxrl7 xraylib libxrl7-dev libxrlf03-7 libxrl-perl
```

Comment: Many thanks for Your answer, however, I found it failed - put the explanation in a separate post.